# java regex to split a string by certain characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to split a string by WHITE_SPACE, LPAREN or RPAREN.

I've tried this:

```
String st = "( a * b - (c * d )";
String[] subs = split.("(\\s+|\\(|\\))");
```

This kind of works, but it gives me empty strings in `subs`.

I expected to get `"a"`, `"*"`, `"-"`, `"c"`, `"*"`, `"d"`.
But I actually got `""`, `""`, `"a"`, `"*"`, `"-"`, `"c"`, `"*"`, `"d"`. (basically, a bunch of extra empty strings)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong, since you have `(` and a space at the start, you're getting empty tokens.

Comment: How do I eliminate the empty tokens?

Comment: `subs = st.replaceFirst("^[()\\s]+", "").split("[()\\s]+");`